# Drawing a texture in a texture fast using Unity 3D?

Tags: unity-game-engine, textures

I have multiple ALPHA8 textures I need to blend into one ALPHA8 texture using Unity 3D, as an intermediate step to create fast dynamic lights. This happens every frame, so I am looking for the most efficient way to do it. SetPixels/apply is way too slow.

Basically I am looking for something like this dummy method:

textureDest.drawTextureAdditive(textureSrc,x,y);

Where x and y are the coordinates where the texture is to be drawn. Has to support clipping since the source texture is much bigger than the destination texture.

The source texture should be drawn on the destination texture using additive blending.

I currently do not have a pro license, so I am not sure if it is possible to do this in the free version at all?

Comment: With Unity free all you've really got is SetPixel/SetPixels, as Unity Pro has rendertextures (which may be your solution). Have you looked into writing a shader that does what you want?

Comment: Yes, I have considered a shader. The problem is the blended low res shadowmap will be stretched across the whole highres screen. I would like to keep the expensive blending at the same low resolution as the shadowmap, then use a cheaper shader for stretching the shadowmap over a high resolution screen. In the end I decided to simply use setpixels, and lower the resolution of the shadowmap.